# Android Emulator Force closes when loading Custom Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I created a custom layout where I have a couple of LinearLayout in a ScrollView. Problem is when I set my layout in `setContentView()` to my custom layout (when the application starts), the emulator gives an error and force closes! I don't know why. I have tried with another custom layout or set it to main and it seems to work fine.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

---

Yes, I meant to say the app is crashing. Here is the xml code for the custom layout: (too many spinners!)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Name"
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:gravity="center">
        </TextView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/Picker"
                android:text="@string/drinkText"
                android:textColor="#303030">
            </TextView>

            <View
                android:layout_height="5dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/TimePicker"
                android:text="@string/TimeText"
                android:textColor="#303030">
            </TextView>

            <View 
                android:layout_height="20dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@id/EndPicker"
                android:text="@string/EndText"
                android:textColor="#303030">
            </TextView>

            <View
                android:layout_height="5dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@id/sortPicker"
                android:text="@string/sortText"
                android:textColor="#303030">
            </TextView>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Categories:"
                android:id="@+id/CategorySelect"/>

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/categorySpinner"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
                android:prompt="@string/categoriesPrompt"
                android:visibility="visible"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Priority:"
                android:id="@+id/prioritySelect"/>

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/prioritySpinner"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
                android:prompt="@string/priorityPrompt"
                android:visibility="visible" android:layout_weight="0.0"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="State:"
                android:id="@+id/stateSelect"/>

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/statusSpinner"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
                android:prompt="@string/statusPrompt"
                android:visibility="visible"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Reminder:"
                android:id="@+id/Reminder"/>

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/remindSpinner"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
                android:prompt="@string/remindPrompt"
                android:visibility="visible"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:background="#FF303030">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="suggestions:"
                android:typeface="sans">
            </TextView>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: You mean to say the app is crashing or the entire emulator is crashing? Posting Code will help finding the problem.

Comment: There is probably a problem with your custom layout.  It would help to see the code.

Comment: It may also help to see the LogCat output.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're specifying a view without including a required attribute (`layout_width`).

```
<View android:layout_height="5dp"/>
```

It's up to you to define the expected behavior for width, but here's one example that will fix your problem:

```
<View android:layout_height="5dp" layout_width="fill_parent" />
```

The Android developer documentation indicates these fields are **required** (source: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/layout-resource.html).